# Grafana dashboard - Cannot remove existing panel from dashboard (unused panel)

Tags: configuration, panel, dashboard, grafana

Appreciate your kind help - I have built an awesome dashboard with few panels.
Now I would like to remove table panel which is not needed - but the trash icon not works and also the remove option in left navigation not works :(

Can you please advise how to delete the unused table panel?

Many thanks
Ron

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI remove options are not working for you:

1. Save your dashboard as json.
2. Open the saved dashboard.json on your local pc.
3. remove the json entry for your unwanted panel.
4. import your edited dashboard.json into grafana.

And maybe report the issue to: https://github.com/grafana/grafana